# Is it possible for someone to send messages from my phone and seem like if I send it to them?

Tags: iphone, sms, gsm

Ok so there's this guy who pays my iPhone6 and lately it's been sending messages to him as if I was the person who typed it but it wasn't me... Does anyone get me? Someone please help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "pays my iPhone6"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is very possible it's called sms spoofing. I have done it once before using a company such as txtNation. Companies like txtNation allow you to send sms from pretty much any phone number or 5 letter name. I will also add that sending a sms from a phone number you don't own is illegal in most countries

Comment: For clarification, does this require access to the phone (ie is the phone compromised?)?

Comment: No access required